# android:show images in gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am making an app in which i want to show list of images in my application in the manner ,  as the images are shown in gallery.The images will get load dynamically. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Android's MediaStore.images class to list all the images in the device

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

You can get the solution from this tutorial

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple/

Answer (score 1):

A nice and easy tutorial here : http://www.anddev.org/a_androidwidgetgallery_-_example-t332.html

if you want to load your images dynamically, create a function in the BaseAdapter and call it into the constructor to load them at the start of the view for example...